# fundamental definition of complex used to solve problem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Suppose $z^2$ is real and negative; that is $z^2 = (a,0), a<0$. Show that $z =(0,b)$ and find $b$ in terms of $a$.

Now taking the square of $z^2 = (a,0)$ won't work especially since $a$ is negative. I thought perhaps trying to use the conclusion we are working towards, i.e. $z=(0,b)$, then working back. Is it fair to say that if $z = (0,b)$  then $z^2 = (0,b)(0,b) = (b',0)$, where $b'$ is the product of the two complex numbers, it is real?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Damn....a down vote though? Funny, i actually just installed  latex on my laptop yesterday and i'm going to start learning it this weekend, it's getting irritating for me too writing complicated questions and the format is crappy

Comment: Yeah, the downvote seems ridiculously harsh to me as well. Here's an upvote to compensate :)

Comment: I'm sorry, @dc3rd. You're right. That was harsh of me :)

Answer (score 2):

We have $z^2=a<0$. Some thought leads to the conclusion that we must arrive at $z=\pm\sqrt{-a}i$. To show this formally using the definiton, write $z:=(x,y)$. Then $z^2=(x^2-y^2,2xy)=(a,0)$. By equality of complex numbers, this implies, in particular, $2xy=0$, so $x=0$ or $y=0$. Now $y=0$ is impossible since we would have $x^2=a<0$ and we know $x^2\geq0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Hence $x=0$, and this leads to $-y^2=a$, that is, $y=\pm\sqrt{-a}$.

Comment: Now, i thought we could not do (-a)^1/2 because that would be a takimg a negative square root and all our numbers are supposed to be elements of the reals?

Comment: @dc3rd $a$ is negative, so $-a$ is positive and $\sqrt{-a}$ is real.

Comment: Ah. Your right. Thanks